# positioning checkboxes at the right side of the container and aligned vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the check boxes to be positioned like the image below:

[image]

Note that the checkboxes should be placed at the same vertical align.

```css
.feedback {
    background: rgb(242 237 241 / 90%);
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60%;
    left: 5%;
    top: 23%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;

   box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 4px #000000;
}
.feedback__form {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.feedback__form h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

button:active, :focus {
  outline: none !important;
}

.btn {
  background-position: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Inter", san-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.btn--primary {
  background-color: #7BC4CA;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(123, 196, 202, 0.7);
}
.btn--primary:hover {
  background: #70bfc6 radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, #70bfc6 1%) center/15000%;
}
.btn--primary:active {
  background-color: #8dccd1;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}
.btn--secondary {
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.7);
}
.btn--secondary:hover {
  background: gainsboro radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, gainsboro 1%) center/15000%;
}
.btn--secondary:active {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}

.burmanRadio {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.burmanRadio__input {
  display: none;
}
.burmanRadio__input:checked ~ .burmanRadio__label::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.burmanRadio__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
.burmanRadio__label::before, .burmanRadio__label::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5px;
  right: -35px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 2;
}
.burmanRadio__label::before {
  content: "";
  border: 1.5px solid #E4E4E4;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.burmanRadio__label::after {
  content: "";
  background: #7ccc25;
  border: 1.5px solid #7BC4CA;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Material-Design-Iconic-Font";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.burmanRadio__label:hover::before {
  border-color: #7BC4CA;
}
```

```html
        <main class="feedback">
          <article class="feedback__form">
          
            <h1 class="feedback__question">We wish to know what put you off!</h1>
            
            <div class="burmanRadio">
              <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-1" name="burmanRadio" checked>
              <label for="radio-1" class="burmanRadio__label">Solution was not clear/correct</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="burmanRadio">
              <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-2" name="burmanRadio">
              <label for="radio-2" class="burmanRadio__label">Solution was not available</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="burmanRadio">
              <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-3" name="burmanRadio">
              <label for="radio-3" class="burmanRadio__label">Price is too high</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="burmanRadio">
              <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-4" name="burmanRadio">
              <label for="radio-4" class="burmanRadio__label">Not needed anymore</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="burmanRadio">
              <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-5" name="burmanRadio">
              <label for="radio-5" class="burmanRadio__label">Other reasons</label>
            </div>
            

          </article>
          

          
        </main>
```

Comment: I would recommend you read up on CSS Flexbox and CSS Grid.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple!!!

Comment: @SaraRee Wrap the divs that have the class of "burmanRadio" with a parent div around all of them give it a class of 'wrapper'. then in css :   `  .wrapper{
   display:flex;   
   flex-direction: column; 
   justify-content:center; 
align-items:center; 
 
}` 
Then doing some research on flexbox will help more, but i hope its a good starting point

Comment: actually with flexbox it is that simple. `flex-direction: row-reverse; ` to alignt them to the right side `align-items: center;` to vertically center them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.burmanRadio__label` to have display `inline-block` instead of default `inline`, make it have an fixed width of `250px` and set `text-align` to `right` adjust `top`, `right`, `width` and `height` properties accordingly to the layout and you're done. Also remove `height: 60%` and use `min-height: 60%` instead, it will be better in most cases.

```css
.feedback {
  background: rgb(242 237 241 / 90%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 60%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 23%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 4px #000000;
}

.feedback__form {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.feedback__form h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.burmanRadio {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.burmanRadio__input {
  display: none;
}

.burmanRadio__input:checked~.burmanRadio__label::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.burmanRadio__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}

.burmanRadio__label::before,
.burmanRadio__label::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -45px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

.burmanRadio__label::before {
  content: "";
  border: 1.5px solid #E4E4E4;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.burmanRadio__label::after {
  content: "";
  background: #7ccc25;
  border: 1.5px solid #7BC4CA;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Material-Design-Iconic-Font";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.burmanRadio__label:hover::before {
  border-color: #7BC4CA;
}
```

```html
<main class="feedback">
  <article class="feedback__form">

    <h1 class="feedback__question">We wish to know what put you off!</h1>

    <div class="burmanRadio">
      <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-1" name="burmanRadio" checked>
      <label for="radio-1" class="burmanRadio__label">Solution was not clear/correct</label>
    </div>

    <div class="burmanRadio">
      <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-2" name="burmanRadio">
      <label for="radio-2" class="burmanRadio__label">Solution was not available</label>
    </div>

    <div class="burmanRadio">
      <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-3" name="burmanRadio">
      <label for="radio-3" class="burmanRadio__label">Price is too high</label>
    </div>

    <div class="burmanRadio">
      <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-4" name="burmanRadio">
      <label for="radio-4" class="burmanRadio__label">Not needed anymore</label>
    </div>

    <div class="burmanRadio">
      <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-5" name="burmanRadio">
      <label for="radio-5" class="burmanRadio__label">Other reasons</label>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Using flexbox and grid would be better.

Edit: If you need to align all the options to the right as on the image then you can just wrap then into a div and align it correctly.

```css
.feedback {
  background: rgb(242 237 241 / 90%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 60%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 23%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 4px #000000;
}

.feedback__form {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.feedback__form h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

button:active,
 :focus {
  outline: none !important;
}

.btn {
  background-position: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Inter", san-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.options {
  text-align: right;
}

.burmanRadio {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.burmanRadio__input {
  display: none;
}

.burmanRadio__input:checked~.burmanRadio__label::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.burmanRadio__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}

.burmanRadio__label::before,
.burmanRadio__label::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -45px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

.burmanRadio__label::before {
  content: "";
  border: 1.5px solid #E4E4E4;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.burmanRadio__label::after {
  content: "";
  background: #7ccc25;
  border: 1.5px solid #7BC4CA;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Material-Design-Iconic-Font";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.burmanRadio__label:hover::before {
  border-color: #7BC4CA;
}
```

```html
<main class="feedback">
  <article class="feedback__form">

    <h1 class="feedback__question">We wish to know what put you off!</h1>

    <div class="options">
      <div class="burmanRadio">
        <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-1" name="burmanRadio" checked>
        <label for="radio-1" class="burmanRadio__label">Solution was not clear/correct</label>
      </div>

      <div class="burmanRadio">
        <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-2" name="burmanRadio">
        <label for="radio-2" class="burmanRadio__label">Solution was not available</label>
      </div>

      <div class="burmanRadio">
        <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-3" name="burmanRadio">
        <label for="radio-3" class="burmanRadio__label">Price is too high</label>
      </div>

      <div class="burmanRadio">
        <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-4" name="burmanRadio">
        <label for="radio-4" class="burmanRadio__label">Not needed anymore</label>
      </div>

      <div class="burmanRadio">
        <input type="radio" class="burmanRadio__input" id="radio-5" name="burmanRadio">
        <label for="radio-5" class="burmanRadio__label">Other reasons</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Make your own attempt before asking for code next time.